# Animate div on hover and mouseleave with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

I have the blue div which should be animated on hover over the green div.

So if you keep the cursor on the green div long enough, the blue div expands. When you move the cursor away, the blue div goes back to it's original size.

But if you just move the mouse quickly over the green div, nothing should happen. This part of this behavior is exactly what my question is. How to solve it?

http://jsfiddle.net/H435A/

```
$('#c').hover(function(){
    $('#nav').delay(150).animate({'top':'-=10px', 'left':'-=10px', 'width':'+=20px', 'height':'+=20px', 'background-color':'orange'}, {duration : 200});
    }, function() {
    $('#nav').stop(true).delay(150).animate({'top':'+=0px', 'left':'+=0px', 'width':'-=0px', 'height':'-=0px', 'background-color':'blue'}, {duration : 200});
});

$('#c').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#nav').animate({'top':'+=10px', 'left':'+=10px', 'width':'-=20px', 'height':'-=20px', 'background-color':'blue'}, {duration : 100});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go, on the `mouseleave` event you just need to check if the animation has been completed or not: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H435A/1/)**

```
var hovered=false;
$('#c').hover(function(){
    $('#nav').delay(150).animate({'top':'-=10px', 'left':'-=10px', 'width':'+=20px', 'height':'+=20px', 'background-color':'orange'}, 200,function(){
        hovered=true;
    });
    }, function() {
    $('#nav').stop(true).delay(150).animate({'top':'+=0px', 'left':'+=0px', 'width':'-=0px', 'height':'-=0px', 'background-color':'blue'},200);
});

$('#c').mouseleave(function(){
    if(hovered==true){
        hovered=false;
        $('#nav').animate({'top':'+=10px', 'left':'+=10px', 'width':'-=20px', 'height':'-=20px', 'background-color':'blue'},100);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach may be heavy on the browser. I think it would be better idea to use CSS3 transitions in this case. Try to apply these rules to your stylesheet:

```
#c {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#c:hover, #c:focus {
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .2s;
    transition-delay: .2s;
}
```

Of course you need to change them a bit. I assigned some random static width and height values because I can't get them from your code example but it works the way you are trying to achieve.

Here is working example: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8b27p/)**

**UPDATE**

I made another example where CSS approach is used in your code. Sorry I missed it before. [Take a look!](http://jsfiddle.net/547XX/)

Comment: +1 I think this should be accepted as an answer, people should not rely on heavy js animations, css transitions should be used to do animations on the web. Javascript should be only used to add or remove possible animation classes.

Comment: 1. wide compatibility is very important for me, 2. java can do much more than css - this is just small part of functionality, and 3. this fiddle is not at all what I need.